# How good is "bitcoin-trader.biz"?

Tags: trading

I've just come across a web site called bitcoin-trader.biz, and they offer membership in a "trading pool" starting at $20.

How good is this company?

Comment: cheap and nonsense domain name like bitcoin-trader.biz already give a clue, it's start by cheap amateur. chance when this exchange have about 10 or 20 bitcoins it will disappear.

Comment: Product and Service Reviews are off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

Their claims are, IMO, implausible. If they're not in it for an honest profit, what are they in it for? If they are in it for an honest profit, what do they need your money for?

They're essentially borrowing money from their customers and saying that they are very, very likely to pay off at an above-market interest rate. Well, why would they do that? Any company in reasonable financial shape can borrow money at near market interest rates.

Also, claims to be doing arbitrage are frequently covers for Ponzi schemes. With no records of their trades, as far as I can tell, their business is a black box. If you can't tell what someone is doing, you shouldn't be helping them do it.

If there is any reason whatsoever to believe that they are actually doing arbitrage and not in fact either running a Ponzi or doing a "buy, hold, and skim", I could't find it on their site.

They also appear to be completely anonymous, and as far as I can tell nobody with any credibility will vouch that they even exist. Why would anyone trust them with their money? An anonymous "financial" company explaining [their own KYC](https://bitcoin-trader.biz/kyc.php) policy is comedy gold, IMO.